# java display weird character on MAC platform

Tags: java, string, macos, character-encoding

I wrote a GUI java program, it can display characters correctly on Windows, but when i run this program on mac, something bad happens.

here's what it shows on both Windows and Mac

Windows --> หุ้น/189,000 (this is the correct one)

Mac --> ���/189,000 (this is the wrong one)

What should i do to make it display correctly on both platforms

thanks

Comment: This happens because `หุ้น` cannot be represented using the character encoding scheme you are using. It could be related to the console also to which you are trying to print them.

Comment: Have you specified the character encoding in both your text editor and your compiler settings? It needs to be a value that is supported on both platforms, such as UTF-8. Windows defaults to CP-1252, which may not be available on other platforms

Comment: thanks all of you above, now i can fix this problem. actually, the message received from internet so i think because of its original encoding ruins my program. so, when i receive the message instead of saving it to String directly, I have to receive in bytes and save it something like this

String str = new String(byteArray, "ISO-8859-1") and it works